# source control when starting up a new project

Tags: version-control, project-management

when starting with a project and using source control i find it hard to separate the things people are working on so they don't either write duplicate code or think it should be named one thing and so on.
this problem diminishes over time because the general foundation is in place and it's easier to separate the tasks so they don't overlap as much

<strike>how do you manage working with source control in the beginning phase?</strike>

**EDIT:** 
I can see that it don't really have anything to do with source control, but it gets more apparent when you have source control too. so the question becomes more along the lines of "how do you manage to separate the tasks so they don't overlap too much. I think it's really hard and i haven't really seen much about how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as far as source control goes, somebody needs to take the lead and set up the basic structure of the project, directories, etc. and communicate it to the team.  On projects I work on, this is usually an architect or senior developer, someone who knows the best practices for project organization for the team/company.

With respect to avoiding having multiple people working on the same tasks, that's a project management function; someone needs to determine what tasks need to be done, and communicate it to the team.  If you are working in an agile/scrum environment, the team may divide and hand out work items amongst themselves, but in either case you need to communicate to avoid doing the same work twice.

**EDIT**

To address the issue of multiple people working on the same task, I tend to work on smaller teams, 2-6 people; in this environment, I have had a lot of success with a [scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development))-influenced approach using the [Crystal Clear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear_(software_development)) methodology:

1. Architect(s)/designer(s) come up with high level design
2. Architect(s)/designer(s) define iterations/deliveries, the first of which is a "project skeleton" which consists of architectural and back-end components and a thin slice of the app
3. Lead person breaks up features into 1-3 day tasks/units of work (estimated)
4. Team meets and discusses priority, timing and dependencies of tasks, and divides up the first set of tasks
5. The team has brief daily meetings to discuss status/priorities and dependencies, and change direction if necessary

With larger projects/teams, you will almost certainly need someone whose main job is dedicated to tracking status, dependencies and conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think source control has much to do with the problem of coordinating people's efforts (except that it can catch some "conflicts" when people erroneously try to modify the same files in different ways -- but, that's not as good as preventing conflicts, and even just "preventing conflicts" does not per se ensure that everybody is working on what they should ideally be working right now, in terms of priorities).  Coordination is properly managed with practices (and perhaps tools, e.g. [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) -- but, using the right practices is even more important than using nice tools!-) that specifically focus on ensuring coordination.  For example, the practices that Tracker is designed to support and enhance, such as story-based iterative planning, and other compatible ones, such as [stand-ups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-up_meeting), offer ways to meet these needs.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a base version that everyone is using, check that into the repository, and then make incremental changes to the repository, make sure that everyone works on different part of the code, commit every working change, and resolve conflicts as and when they occur. That is how I would do it.